# Setting EditIndex of GridView makes elements in EditItemTemplate not updated

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview like

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdArticles" runat="server" 
    OnRowEditing="grdArticles_OnRowEditing">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>                                                                    
        <%#Eval("num") %> st                                                                
      </ItemTemplate>                                                                
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNum" Width="30px" Text='<%#Eval("num") %>' 
          runat="server"/>                                                                
      </EditItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

which is populated with

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      grdArticles.DataSource = Repo.GetArticles();
      grdArticles.DataBind();
    }        
}
```

and grdArticles_OnRowEditing is like

```
protected void grdArticles_OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
  grdArticles.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
}
```

When I press the edit button, the textbox will come up instead of the bare text but it will not have the text corresponding to `num`. It comes up empty instead.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Add `grdArticles.DataBind();` after updating EditIndex like shown below:

```
protected void grdArticles_OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
  grdArticles.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
  grdArticles.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: That will remove the items. As I understand, you need to refetch them (and also set DataSource before DataBind here), but I do not want to do that, because I do not want to rely on the database having the same records the second time.

Comment: Have you tried it without setting the Datasource and just calling the DataBind() method as suggested?

Comment: Yes, and that will remove the items.